# Get data out of case statement C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sdk, switch-statement

I'm using an SDK of a thermal cam we bought. Actually I'm a PHP Web developer and now I have to write code in .Net

So there is a case but I really don't know how I could get the data out of it.

```
 private void OnDetect(CallbackEventArgument callbackArgument)
 {
    var detectionResult = callbackArgument.GetDetectionResult();
    var firstDetection = detectionResult.Sequence.Items.First();

    var message = string.Empty;
    ImageArgument fullSizeImage = null;
    switch (detectionResult.Type)
    {
       case T3DDetectionType.OBSERVATION:
          message = "Track ID: " + firstDetection.TrackId;
          fullSizeImage = detectionResult.RGBImage;
          break;
       case T3DDetectionType.DEPTH_LIVENESS:
       case T3DDetectionType.THERMAL_LIVENESS:
          message = "Track ID: " + firstDetection.TrackId + " Score: " + (firstDetection as Liveness).Score.ToString("N0");
          fullSizeImage = detectionResult.FullImage;
          break;
       case T3DDetectionType.TEMPERATURE:
          message = "Temperature: " + (firstDetection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1") + "°C";
          fullSizeImage = detectionResult.FullImage;
          break;
    }
```

So what I would like to do is be able to get the data of `(firstDetection as Liveness).Score.ToString("N0")`, `firstDetection.TrackId` and `(firstDetection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1") + "°C"` after the case and create a JSON.

Creating a json works but I just can't call the data.

Comment: What do you mean? do you want to get that Json which created inside case `T3DDetectionType.DEPTH_LIVENESS:`?

Comment: I want to get the value of  `(firstDetection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1")`, dont mind about the JSON. I just want to use the data of this variable out of the switch statement

Comment: When creating a json string in c# I would be thinking in terms of serialisation. Build an object and serialise to json. There are several very odd things I see in there though. You're going to send a picture as json? I would expect an enum.  Why do you care about string format? I would expect that to be the job of whatever receives the json. It seems odd you have different variables as well. This would be a different class serialised or maybe just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something out of your switch statement then simply do following:

- Declare a variable before the switch statement

```
string firstDetection = string.Empty;
```

- And assign your required value to that variable inside the switch case.

```
case T3DDetectionType.TEMPERATURE:
   message = "Temperature: " + (firstDetection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1") + "°C";
   firstDetection = (firstDetection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1") + "°C";
   fullSizeImage = detectionResult.FullImage;
   break;
```

Now, after switch statement you will be having your required value in variable `firstDetection`.